# Convert an XML into readable CSV using PHP

Tags: php, xml, algorithm, csv

I am trying to parse my XML file and create a new CSV file based on the XML file.

To be accurate, I have this XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generated by Oracle Reports version 12.2.1.4.0 -->
<REAL_ESTATE_OVERVIEW>
    <NAME>Mike Wazovski</NAME>
    <DATETIME>2022-09-23T16:30:45</DATETIME>
    <ESTATES>
        <ESTATE>
            <NAME>Son's house</NAME>
            <ROOMS>
                <ROOM>
                    <ID>MH_R_01</ID>
                    <AREA>66</AREA>
                </ROOM>
                <ROOM>
                    <ID>MH_R_02</ID>
                    <AREA>86</AREA>
                    <BEDS>2</BEDS>
                </ROOM>
            </ROOMS>
        </ESTATE>
        <ESTATE>
            <NAME>Wife's house</NAME>
            <ROOMS>
                <ROOM>
                    <ID>PH_R_01</ID>
                    <AREA>75</AREA>
                    <BEDS>2</BEDS>
                </ROOM>
                <ROOM>
                    <ID>PH_R_02</ID>
                    <AREA>77</AREA>
                </ROOM>
            </ROOMS>
        </ESTATE>
    </ESTATES>
</REAL_ESTATE_OVERVIEW>
```

And I want the final formatted CSV to look like this:

[image: Final CSV]

I got this idea of getting all nodes' names into an array `$headers` and all nodes' values into another array `$row`:

```php
$xmlStr = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generated by Oracle Reports version 12.2.1.4.0 -->
<REAL_ESTATE_OVERVIEW>
    <NAME>Mike Wazovski</NAME>
    <DATETIME>2022-09-23T16:30:45</DATETIME>
    <ESTATES>
        <ESTATE>
            <NAME>Son's house</NAME>
            <ROOMS>
                <ROOM>
                    <ID>MH_R_01</ID>
                    <AREA>66</AREA>
                </ROOM>
                <ROOM>
                    <ID>MH_R_02</ID>
                    <AREA>86</AREA>
                    <BEDS>2</BEDS>
                </ROOM>
            </ROOMS>
        </ESTATE>
        <ESTATE>
            <NAME>Wife's house</NAME>
            <ROOMS>
                <ROOM>
                    <ID>PH_R_01</ID>
                    <AREA>75</AREA>
                    <BEDS>2</BEDS>
                </ROOM>
                <ROOM>
                    <ID>PH_R_02</ID>
                    <AREA>77</AREA>
                </ROOM>
            </ROOMS>
        </ESTATE>
    </ESTATES>
</REAL_ESTATE_OVERVIEW>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlStr);

function loopXml($xml, &$headers, &$row) {
    foreach ($xml->children() as $item) {
        $hasChild = count($item->children()) > 0;
        if (!$hasChild) {
            array_push($headers, $item->getName());
            array_push($row, (string) $item[0]);
        } else {
            array_push($headers, $item->getName());
            array_push($row, '');
            loopXml($item, $headers, $row);
        }
    }
}

$headers = array();
$row = array();

loopXml($xml, $headers, $row);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($headers);
echo "</pre>\n";

echo "<pre>";
print_r($row);
echo "</pre>";
```

[image: Arrays]

But I can't figure out how this could help me stack the same-level children on top of each other, like this:

[image: Final array]

Comment: The short answer without any code is to loop over each `ESTATE` and then inside of that, loop over each `ROOM`. You are going to run into some issues because you are making "presentable CSV" which means a lot of blank fields that only exist for presentation reasons. Personally I'd go from XML to actual objects to CSV, I don't like to use arbitrary arrays to store data that is in a known format, but that's just me.

Comment: The "print_r($headers)" and "print_r($row)" give what you show....?
Because if that's the case you just have to go through those arrays.